# How to use a validates inside an custom validation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I use easy_globalize3_accessor for set translated field and I would like to test a set of fields like that:

```
class ClientTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :content, :subject, :translated_presence => {:locales => Proc.new{|template| template.client.languages.map(&:locale)}}
end
```

So I created a new custom validator like this but not seems to works :

```
class TranslatedPresenceValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    (options[:locales].call(record) || I18n.available_locales).each do |locale|
      record.class.validates "#{attribute}_#{locale}".to_sym, :presence => true
    end
  end
end
```

question is simple, How to call validates ?

thanks.

UPDATE:

```
validates :content, :subject, :no_internationalization_blank => {
    :locales => Proc.new{|template| template.client.languages.map(&:locale)}
}
```

with:

```
class NoInternationalizationBlankValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    options[:locales].call(record).each do |locale|
      record.errors[attribute] << I18n.t("activerecord.errors.messages.blank_internationalization", 
  :language => I18n.t("languages.%s" % locale).downcase) if record.send(attribute.to_s.concat("_%s" % locale)).blank?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
[...]
record.class.instance_eval do
  validates "#{attribute}_#{locale}".to_sym, :presence => true
end
[...]
```

Comment: in fact, there's no need for a validator i think. instead, you might wanna create a class method that adds those generators with dynamic `:if` conditions.

like


`class Foo < AR::Base
apply_validators :bar
`

and `apply_validators` would just create a bunch of validators behind the scene